# railsでuser showの方だけActionController::UrlGenerationErrorが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsでいいね機能の非同期化したいです。

indexの方ではエラーが出ないのですが、user showの方で以下のエラーが出ます。ネットで検索してルーティングの確認をしたり、book.idが空になっているのでおそらくコントローラーに問題があると思い、引数を変えてみましたが解決しません。
どこをなおしたら良いかわかりません。
また、見づらい部分もあるかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Users#show
Showing /home/ec2-user/environment/rails6-bookers2-debug-ruby3-main/app/views/favorites/_favorite.html.erb where line #7 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :book_id=>nil, :controller=>"favorites"}, missing required keys: [:book_id]
Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10
              
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to book_favorites_path(book), method: :post, remote: true,data: {"turbolinks" => false} do %>
    <i class="fas fa-heart" ></i>
     <%= book.favorites.count %>
  <% end %>

Trace of template inclusion: #<ActionView::Template app/views/books/_index.html.erb locals=["books"]>, #<ActionView::Template app/views/users/show.html.erb locals=[]>
```

gem 'jquery-rails'を導入しています。

該当していると思われるコードを記載します。

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!

  #belongs_to :user
  #sbelongs_to :book

  def create
   @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
   favorite = current_user.favorites.new(book_id: @book.id)
   favorite.save
   #redirect_to books_path
  end

  def destroy
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    favorite = current_user.favorites.find_by(book_id: @book.id)
    favorite.destroy
    #redirect_to books_path
  end
end
```

_favorite.html

```
<% if book.favorited_by?(current_user)  %>
  <%= link_to  book_favorites_path(book), method: :delete, remote: true, data: {"turbolinks" => false} do %>
      <i class="fas fa-heart", style="color:red;" ></i>
       <%= book.favorites.count %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to book_favorites_path(book), method: :post, remote: true,data: {"turbolinks" => false} do %>
    <i class="fas fa-heart" ></i>
     <%= book.favorites.count %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

create.js

```
$('#favorite_buttons_<%= @book.id %>').html("<%= j(render "favorites/favorite", book: @book) %>");
```

destroy.js

```
$('#favorite_buttons_<%= @book.id %>').html("<%= j(render "favorites/favorite", book: @book) %>");
```

assets/javascript/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  devise_for :users
  root to: "homes#top"
  get 'home/about'=>'homes#about', as: 'about'
  post 'books' => 'books#create'


  resources :books, only: [:index,:show,:edit,:create,:destroy,:update,:new] do
  resource :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :book_comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

  resources :users, only: [:index,:show,:edit,:update]
  get 'search' => 'searches#search'

  resources :users do
    resource :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
    get 'followings' => 'relationships#followings', as: 'followings'
    get 'followers' => 'relationships#followers' , as: 'followers'
  end
  #get 'search' => 'searches#search'
end
```

Comment: コードやエラーメッセージは [ヘルプページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) を参考に Markdown で装飾してもらうと見やすくなりますので、次回以降試してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Users#show` とあるので気にするべきは UsersController と users#show の view です。_favorite.html.erb で `link_to book_favorites_path(book)` を生成したいのに `book.id` が `nil` なのでエラーになっています。View で _favorite.html.erb をレンダリングする際にちゃんと id 付きの `book` が渡っているか確かめてみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。遅くなってすみません。ご指摘いただいたところ確認してみて解決しました。